# Dual Boot-Microsoft Word

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, microsoft-word

I have windows 7 alongside with Ubuntu 14.04, but my windows is not working anymore(blue screen of death). What I want to do, is to open and use microsoft word from my ubuntu. Is that any close to possible? To be clear, WinWord is already installed on my windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run Microsoft Windows from your Windows partition without first doing a lot of hackery in Wine to make this work, and its unlikely to work cleanly either.

Wine will run from its own prefix stored inside your home directory in LInux - it does not easily work with the windows partition in a dualboot setup.

Your best bet would be to install Office in Wine, or use a Windows virtual machine and load up Office inside it (which is what I do because I *have* to use office for school)

Comment: I thought of that too, but i was hoping that there was a solution without the help of a third program. @ThomasW.

Comment: @sy7 Unfortunately, you can't just make Wine work with the Windows install - it's very difficult to make it work that way.